# What is the purpose of the ['moved to'] array variable in Views $data array?

Tags: 7, views

I'm learning how to do views handlers and looking over a few modules and noticed that there is a **'moved to'** array variable set sometimes. I have the following line in the bulk views operations module:

```
$data[$info['base table']]['views_bulk_operations']['moved to'] = array('views_entity_' . $entity_type, 'views_bulk_operations');
```

What is this line doing by setting the **'moved to'** array to **array('views_entity_' . $entity_type, 'views_bulk_operations')** ?

Below i have a new handler I made by copying similar part of the code from the bulk views operations module into the flag list operations module and changing a few things. When setting the **moved to** array, it breaks the above handler. why and what is the purupose of the **moved to** array setting?

[image]